# jQuery Isotope -webkit-transform rendering issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been hacking at jquery isotope for awhile now and I am having an issue in chrome/safari in particular. The layout renders out like this:[in Google Chrome/Safari](http://www.johnnytrinh.com/v4z/troubleshoot.jpg). When you resize the window or hit the filter buttons, they will shift out normally. Upon inspecting the code I see that the -webkit-transform: translate is saying that only a part of the picture is shown.

I've stripped the code and started from scratch to make sure I wasn't missing any steps, but this is incredibly frustrating as it seems like its only a Chrome/Safari issue whereas IE9/Firefox4 seem to be rendering this correctly.

I've tried to disable transform and css rendering, but that doesn't have any effect as it still renders the pictures stacked and cropped off. Testing it locally it sometimes bugs out like the picture I uploaded but other times its fine.

I've uploaded the page to this directory: [click here](http://www.johnnytrinh.com/v4z/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the Isotope docs:

> #### Images
>
> Inline dimensions For images, the best
>   method is to specify the width and
>   height of images inline.
>
> ```
> <img src="img-file.jpg" width="280" height="160" />
> ```

Comment: I've also tried that and the images still stack on top of each other.

Comment: Strange. You using any kind of floats or absolute positioning on those elements?

Comment: No I am not. I tested the answer duopixel has responded with. I will try to add in the width and height specifically. I appreciate the responses.

Comment: I don't like to post "me too" comments, but thank you very much for solving my issue as well, coreyward. +1 for a simple solution.

Answer (score 4):

In your demo I'm getting a different render on every reload. It seems to me the script is firing before the images are completely loaded, which points to coreyward's response: Isotope needs to know the image dimensions. The should be fixed by specifying the width and height of the images.

But, if you want a quick fix and to test if this is the problem, you can fire the script until the images have finished loading with this:

```
$(window).load(function(){  
  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector : '.design'
  });
});
```

Comment: I implemented this and it seems to work. I will try to reimplement what corey had suggested, but for the most part I believe this onload window is helping immensely. Thank you!